# How to display same results from 2 different tables on 2 different lines

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in 2 different databases and the server is same.

Table 1:

```
ID      Name      Address      date
=======================================
1       abc       123 xyz      1-1-2018

2       efg       456 pqr      1-20-2018
```

Table 2:

```
ID     Name      Address       Date
-----------------------------------
1      abc       xxxx         1-1-2017

2      xjy       yyyy         1-20-2017
```

I want results from both tables to display like this:

```
ID     Name     Address       Date
-------------------------------------
1      abc      123 xyz       1-1-2018   This is from table 1

1      abc      xxxx          1-1-2017   This is from table 2
```

How can i display my results like this, in both tables only id is common?

Comment: You're not new. No one should have to guess at what column or columns you need to use to join or "match" rows. Is it ID only? Is it Name" Is it both columns? And what happened to rows where ID = 2? And if you want matching rows to be "next" to each other, you must - **MUST** - use the proper order by clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` :

```
select t.*
from ( (select t1.ID, t1.Name, t1.Address, t1.date
        from table1 t1
        where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
       ) union all
       (select t2.ID, t2.Name, t2.Address, t2.date
        from table2 t2
        where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t2.id = t1.id)
       ) 
     ) t;
```

Comment: The outer `select` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION:

```
select id, [name], address, [date], cast('This is from table 1' as varchar(100))
from table1 where id in (select id from table2)
union
select id, [name], address, [date], cast('This is from table 2' as varchar(100))  
from table2 where id in (select id from table1);
```